# regex as $filter in projection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find (using a regexp) an array field and returns that element only

This is my data

```
  [
 {
"_id": "56d6e8bbf7404bd80a017edb",
"name": "document1",
"tags": [
  "A area1",
  "B area2",
  "C area3"
]
},
{
"_id": "56d6e8bbf7404bd82d017ede",
"name": "document2",
"tags": [
  "b_area3",
  "b_area4",
  "b_area5"
  ]
}
]
```

My query

```
var query=new RegExp('^'+string, "i");

Model.find({tags:query},{'tags.$': 1}, function(err,data){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        res.json(data);
    });
```

This query selects only the tags field (as I want), but selects the first element. I need the element(s) that matches the query.

**EDIT: I tried the mongodb aggregate too, the $filter cond is wrong. I get the error "MongoError: invalid operator $regex"**

```
caseNote.aggregate([
    { $match: {tags:query}},
    { $project: {
        tags: {$filter: {
            input: 'tags',
            as: 'item',
            cond: {$regex: ['$$item', query]}
        }}
    }}
], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.json(result);
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT2: on @zangw suggestion, this is the mongoose version, but it's incomplete: the tags fields is fine (needs test), but the query still returns the whole document.**

```
 caseNote
     .aggregate({ $match: {tags: {$in:['area3']}}})
     .unwind('tags')
     .exec(function(err,d){
         res.json(d);
     });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According this issue [`Use $regex as the expression in a $cond`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8892), the `$regex` could NOT be used with `cond` for current mongo version.

Maybe you can try this one, filter the `area3` through `$match`, then get all matched tags through `$group`, then remove the `_id` through `$project`.

```
caseNote.aggregate([{$unwind: '$tags'},
               {$match: {tags: /area3/}},
               {$group: {_id: null, tags: {$push: '$tags'}}},
               {$project: {tags: 1, _id: 0}}])
    .exec(function(err, tags) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log(tags);
    });
```

Results:

```
{ "tags" : [ "C area3", "b_area3" ] }
```

Comment: @the.websurfer, I have updated my answer with test data. Your previous codes does not follow my answer...

Comment: I'll explain better: I need a plain array of tags that matches the query, something like
`["C area3","b_area3"]`. At this time I guess there is no way to accomplish that straight with a query.

Comment: @alfredopacino, you can do that through `$group`, please refer to my updated answer.

Comment: @alfredopacino, remove the `_id` field through `$project` at the end of aggregation.

Comment: I just tried, it works like a charm, but the aggregation doesn't remove duplicates (I need that).
I guess I will remove by myself after the query,

Answer (score 8):

As per @zangw's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35762216/8987128),

> *this [ISSUE-SERVER-8892](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8892), According this issue Use $regex as the expression in a $cond, the $regex could NOT be used with cond for current mongo version.*

**MongoDB v4.1.11** has launched new features in [ISSUE-SERVER-11947](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947), This features adds three new expressions `$regexFind`, `$regexFindAll` and `$regexMatch` to the aggregation language.

In your example, You can use [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/index.html) expression,

```
Model.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      tags: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$tags",
          cond: {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: "$$this",
              regex: query
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FI3YSkYCL0Q)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it. If the query can be parsed to regex the projection is not added to aggregation, but happening after the db request. If the query string is normal string, the projection added.

```
const { query } = req;  // /rea/ or 'C area3'

const convertIfRegex = string => {
  const parts = string.split('/')
  let regex = string;
  let options = '';

  if (parts.length > 1) {
    regex = parts[1];
    options = parts[2];
  } else {
    return false
  }

  try {
    return new RegExp(regex, options);
  } catch (e) {
    return null
  }
};

const regex = convertIfRegex(queryString);
const aggregations = [{ $match: { tags:query } }]

if (!regex) {
  aggregations.push({
    $project: {
      tags: {$filter: {
        input: 'tags',
        as: 'item',
        cond: {$eq: ['$$item', query]}
      }}
    }
  })
}

let result = await caseNote.aggregate(aggregations);

if (regex) {
  result = result.reduce((acc, entry) => {
    const tags = entry.tags.filter(({ tag }) => (
      tag.match(regex)
    ))
    if (tags.length) return [...acc, { ...entry, tags }];
    return acc;
  })
}

res.json(result)
```